# Why did the integrity checksum in the pacakge-lock.json change only by a few characters?

Tags: checksum, package-lock.json

I wanted to add new npm pacakge to the project. I was not able to, because some packages I already had on my machine seemed to be corrupted. The **integrity checksum (sha512)** in the `package-lock.json` was not matching with the actual checksum.

Unfortunatetly I am not able to tell the reason why the checksum could be different. I was able to fix the problem by deleting `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` directory and installing the pacakges again with `npm i`.

The integrity checksum for some packages changed only by some characters despite no change in the version and it does not seem right to me.

The changes of the characters of the integrity checksum share some similarities:

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| BDC | bDp |
| BDC | bdP |
| BDC | Bdp |
| bdc | bgp |

Could a operating system upgrade from Windows 10 to Windows 11 cause the changes? Is this a security problem? How can I find the root cause of this change?